# Why I am getting warning "Namespace 'System.Web' should not be referenced in ASP.NET Core projects"?

Tags: c#, .net

I usually do HTTP encoding and decoding using the HttpUtility from System.Web. Recently I started to get this warning:

> Namespace 'System.Web' should not be referenced in ASP.NET Core
> projects

Which left me puzzled as I am using .NET 6.0

Answer (score 1):

This warning seems to show that Microsoft is favouring the use of the System.Net instead of System.Web, and specifically for the class HttpUtility you can also see some indications that they recommend the WebUtility (System.Net) instead for general use (other than pure web applications), as seen in the [Microsoft's HttpUtility page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility?view=net-7.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN#Anchor_4)

> The HttpUtility class is used internally by the HttpServerUtility class, whose methods and properties are exposed through the intrinsic ASP.NET Server object. Additionally, the HttpUtility class contains encoding and decoding utility methods that are not accessible from the Server.
>
> To encode or decode values outside of a web application, use the WebUtility class.